# Combo Boxes and Arrays (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I'm working on a project for school and having some issues. I have to use an array with prices to go forward with calculating the cost of a smoothie. The "row" is for the style of smoothie (regular or organic) and the "column" allows the user to decided the size of their smoothie.

I feel like I'll be golden for the rest of the project but I can't seem to find a way to code where I can use SelectedIndex to allow the user to choose the style and size of their smoothie from a list of items I have already populated in the Designer.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Unless you populate the combo box with values like, "Organic - Large", "Regular - Small" (one for each combo) a single combo box isn't the appropriate control here, because the user is selecting two distinct things: size and type

Comment: So you already have the combobox populated the way you want it, you just don't know how to get the value back out?

Comment: You have described two lists, or a two dimensional array. Can you please show how you are storing this data, and give an example of what a line in the combo box would look like? Are you sure you don't want one combo box for `smoothieStyle` and another for `size`?

Comment: You should be showing your code, you can bind an array to a comboxbox. `yourCombobox.DataSource = array.ToArray();`